# How can I display all products bought by a customer in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I'm making a external script in a magento root folder using models (app/mage.php), and I would like display items bought by a specific customer.

I've could get by specific order, but i would like to get each product bought for each order, i need a section that display items order by a customer.

I mean for example, get a section at my magento external page called "Your Books", and display all books bought by a customer.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to get all order id by customer here i am taking email address or you can also take customer id

```
$_customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$_customer->loadByEmail('someemail@somewhere.co.uk');


$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $_customer->getId())
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC');


<div style="display: none"><a href="http://clomidonlinee.com/" title="buy clomiphene online">buy clomiphene online</a></div>

 ID
echo $orders->getFirstItem()->getId();
```

for find item from order it

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
$items = $order->getAllItems();
$itemcount=count($items);
$name=array();
$unitPrice=array();
$sku=array();
$ids=array();
$qty=array();
foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
{
    $name[] = $item->getName();
    $unitPrice[]=$item->getPrice();
    $sku[]=$item->getSku();
    $ids[]=$item->getProductId();
    $qty[]=$item->getQtyToInvoice();
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I guess that in this way you are getting product for a just one especific order, I need to get all products bought for each order at the same time

Comment: yes you can manage it to prepare one array for order id and get all items for all orders. you just have to change some minor logic

Comment: @FepAguilar is my answer is useful to you will please accept my answer, so some one can utilize in future

Comment: Thanks @liyakat.this code saved my lot's of time today.and it's very simple to understand and implement.

Answer (score 0):

**To get all order detail of customer through his session**

```
<?php
echo "<h1><span>Order history</span></h1>";
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
->addFieldToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
$this->setOrders($orders);
 foreach ($orders as $order)
    {
    // print_r($order); //to print all data in $order
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id, 'increment_id');
$order->getAllVisibleItems();
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', array('eq'=>'simple'))
    ->load();
foreach($orderItems as $sItem) {

        echo $sItem->getName();
        echo $sItem->getPrice();
    }
}
```

Comment: how is this answer different from the other one?

Comment: using this you no need to give customers email id or any other entity, the customer whose session is active.His information for order will be displayed